# Possible to improve the performance of this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table that has over 100,000,000 rows and I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF(created_at >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00', 1, null)) AS 'monthly',
    COUNT(IF(created_at >= '2015-07-26 00:00:00', 1, null)) AS 'weekly',
    COUNT(IF(created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56', 1, null)) AS '30day',
    COUNT(IF(created_at >= '2015-07-29 17:03:44', 1, null)) AS 'recent'
FROM
    items
WHERE
    user_id = 123456;
```

The table looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`item_id`),
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`created_at`),
    KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The explain looks fairly harmless, minus the massive row counts:

```
1   SIMPLE  items   ref PRIMARY,user_id user_id 4   const   559864  Using index
```

I use the query to gather counts for a specific user for 4 segments of time.
Is there a smarter/faster way to obtain the same data or is my only option to tally these as new rows are put into this table?

Comment: is there an index on the created_at column? If yes what kind of index? How long does it take to run the query? How often is it executed? As an acutal help: I'm not entirely sure but it should help to add another statement to the `WHERE` statement, something like `AND created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56` so that only relevant data is actually 'counted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an index on created_at field:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX idx_created_at (created_at)
```

or (as Thomas suggested) since you are also filtering for user_id a composite index on created_at and user_id:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX idx_user_created_at (user_id, created_at)
```

and then I would write your query as:

```
SELECT 'monthly' as description, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM items
WHERE created_at >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00' AND user_id = 123456

UNION ALL

SELECT 'weekly' as description, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM items
WHERE created_at >= '2015-07-26 00:00:00' AND user_id = 123456

UNION ALL

SELECT '30day' as description, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM items
WHERE created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56' AND user_id = 123456

UNION ALL

SELECT 'recent' as description, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM items
WHERE created_at >= '2015-07-29 17:03:44' AND user_id = 123456
```

yes, the output is a little different. Or you can use inline queries:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE created_at>=... AND user_id=...) AS 'monthly',
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE created_at>=... AND user_id=...) AS 'weekly',
  ...
```

and if you want an average, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT
  monthly,
  weekly,
  monthly / total,
  weekly / total
FROM (
  SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE created_at>=... AND user_id=...) AS 'monthly',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE created_at>=... AND user_id=...) AS 'weekly',
    ...,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE user_id=...) AS total
) s
```

Comment: would be interesting to see wether this is faster than doing what I wrote in my comment (just extending the current where clause).

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use a composite index of `(created_at, user_id)` ?

Comment: I just tested this and what you suggested @SteffenWinkler and both are very close in terms of performance and both shaved my 5 second query to < 300ms!

Comment: @ThomasTschernich yes, since we are also filtering by user_id I think it is often a good idea, thanks

Comment: I guess I should see what the average item count per user is vs the total item count in a given month, right?

Comment: @prgrmnerd if I understand your request correctly... please see my updated answer

Comment: @fthiella oh, I wasn't looking on how to calculate the average. I was just saying that I should check what it is because if the average is really high, I should make the key be (created_by, user_id) and if the average is really low than I should make the key be (user_id, created_by), right?

Comment: @prgrmnerd ohh sorry, now I get it... yes, as a general rule you should put columns that will be the most selective at the beginning of the index declaration, it depends on how many users you have and how many dates you have, probably it's best to have (created_at, user_id) but even just (created_at) could be enough if many dates and few users... but that depends on how is your data

Comment: @fthiella - No not the 'most selective'; put the '=' columns first; put the 'range' column last.  More discussion [in my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Did you time the UNION versus non-UNION?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on created_at, I would also put in the where clause created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56' which is the lowest date possible in your segment.

Also with the same index it might work splitting in 4 queries:

```
select count(*) AS '30day'
FROM
items
WHERE
    user_id = 123456
and created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56'
union ....
```

And so on

Comment: My god... you sir are a genius on adding the extra where clause being greater than the earliest date in my segments. Love it!

Answer (score 0):

- `INDEX(user_id, created_at)` -- optimal
- `AND created_at >= '2015-06-30 07:57:56'` -- helps because it cuts down on the number of index entries to touch
- Doing a `UNION` does not help since it leads to 4 times as much work.
- Doing for subquery `SELECTs` does not help for the same reason.

Also

```
COUNT(IF(created_at >= '2015-07-29 17:03:44', 1, null))
```

can be shortened to

```
SUM(created_at >= '2015-07-29 17:03:44')
```

(But probably does not speed it up much)

If the data does not change over time, only new rows are added, then Summary tables of past data would lead to a significant speedup, but only if you could avoid things like '07:57:56' for '30day'.  (Why have '00:00:00' for only some of them?)  Perhaps the speedup would be another factor of 10 on top of the other changes.  Want to discuss further?

(I do not see any advantage in using `PARTITION`.)

Comment: I would not say that a UNION is always slower, it depends on how the data is structured - UNION does the work more times, but a COUNT(*) is faster than a COUNT(IIF( ... )) - on this particular context I think that using just an AND is a good idea, probably better than UNION, but if we were counting for example 'weekly this month', 'weekly last month', 'weekly last year' etc. I would expect a UNION query to perform better

Comment: `UNION` _can_ be **faster** when each `SELECT` is making good use of a different index.  Otherwise, `UNION` is _likely_ to be **slower** because of the extra overhead.  In this case, I predict 'slower'.